# Why I cannot use full google calendar feed?

Tags: javascript, json, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a public Google Calendar:

[image]

And I want to read appointment data in JSON format.

I use this URL `https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/{calendar_id}%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?alt=json` and it works fine. But when I use this `https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/{calendar_id}%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json` I have `Error 403`.

So, are there any additional calendar settings that allow read full calendar feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarid}/events?key={Your Public API Key}
```

You have to register a new public api which you can do by register in the google api console (https://console.developers.google.com)